# Suspended mode is not working correctly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, suspend

After I did get my PC into the suspended mode, I can't get the PC on again. In Windows 7 there's no problem at all.

Does it take a very long time to get PC to turn on again from suspended mode in Ubuntu? Because of this problem I did restart the PC at every suspended mode was activated.

Please give me some help on this

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this ubuntuforum thread:

[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Suspend not working FIX by DragonNinja9](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11926504)

Comment: **Not worked.** This is the kernal I'm running on. "_3-2-0-30-generic_" So, I tried a few times..but its not worked for me.

Comment: Hibernate mode still works ?

Comment: ok...I'll try that...we'll see..

Comment: @ErangaFernando: did it work for you? if mark the answer. if not, did you find something that did?